# Exchange 2003 white space

Tags: exchange-2003

I am having an issue with exchange, I am deleting users mail but this is not being reflected in the exchange as the space on the hard drive remains the same, how can I reclaim this space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange reclaims the space and re-uses it. You will have to do an offline defragmentation and compaction of your exchange database files. Ensure that you have a working backup.

Defragmenting a database requires free disk space equal to 110 percent of the size of the database being processed .

```
1. Dismount the the store
2. run eseutil: C:\program files\exchsrvr\bin> eseutil /d c:\progra~1\exchsrvr\mdbdata\priv1.edb
```

You can read more at [support.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192185) just scroll down to the Exchange 2003 section.

Comment: My Priv1.edb database is 161GB in size, I've only got 10GB of free space on a 200GB disk. So this is not going to be an option, is there any other solutions.

Comment: Connect another disk, such as a USB drive and set the path to that drive when doing the offline defrag.